# Can a storyboard be encapsulated?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, encapsulation, uistoryboard

I want to use a storyboard encapsulated in a `UIViewController` to provide a consistent UI throughout the application.
Is there anyway to embed the first `UIViewController` of a storyboard into a 'master' `UIViewController`, then allow the segues and storyboard transitions to function as normal, all within an area of the 'master' `UIViewController`?

Thank you.

Here is the storyboard I'm hoping to embed /
[image: complex storyboard]

Comment: I think you are talking about encapsulating a `UIViewController`. I do not believe a Storyboard could be encapsulated.
 
That being said, you are looking at writing up a pretty big hack to do what you need. You would most likely need to inherit a `UIViewController` and then add views underneath them.

Comment: I've got a work version in ios 6  using the new UIContainerView. However I need to deploy to ios 5.

Comment: I believe Container View Controller is part of iOS 5 as well. what is your error?

Comment: I'm sure Container View is new in ios 6 I can't find a class for it. It seems to only appear in Interface Builder. If you know the class name that would be great. thanks

Comment: I posted a answer to encapsulate `UIViewControllers` with some links on the different methods. and it was available from iOS 5 onwards (might have been improved with features and bug fix in iOS 6).

Comment: @Steven is right. I'm pretty sure that UIViewController Containment was introduced with iOS5.

Comment: HOLY COW!!! you got some work cut out for you. and yea, now i see why you want to use the container view. Not sure how you will do it, but the link mentions the method for you.

Comment: It's actually far bigger than that but I can't fit it on the screen (even fully zoomed out) I'll let you know how my test go. Cheers for the help.

Comment: Thanks Steven, that's worked like a charm. I didn't realise that was brought in for iOS 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use container views for your task.

This link here: http://invasivecode.tumblr.com/post/12383262201/container-view-controllers-part-i-one-of-the

It shows the different methods used to create a Container view. Something like the image below (image courtesy from the [link above](http://www.invasivecode.com/blogimages/hierarchy.jpg)):

[image]

Check out the link, hope it helps.